# Linux - Debugging a floppy disk emulation

Tags: debugging, assembly, nasm

I was wondering if there was any way that I could debug a floppy disk emulation in Linux.

The main thing I want to be able to do is to see the values of registers and custom defined bytes and words as the emulation runs.

Another thing I would like to be able to do is to run the emulation one step at a time, and see what line of code my emulation is currently on.

I am currently just running my floppy disk image under qemu-system-x86_64 and letting it run without any feedback besides the emulation.

If anyone can supply me with something along the lines of command line statements that accomplish this sort of thing, and what programs I could either move to or install alongside to help me out, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can attach `gdb` to `qemu`, although I don't think it handles 16 bit terribly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough idea of **qemu** because I haven't used it much. But from your requirement perspective, I think you should try **bochs** emulator. It's quite easy to use and comes with a built-in debugger. 
Only thing is, you need to compile it from source (if on Linux) making sure the `--enable-debug` and `--enable-disasm` switches are enabled (alongwith any other options you might want to enable). 
 *(On Windows however, the debugger comes as a pre-built (separate) executable in the installation, but that's sort of irrelevant in your case I guess.)*